# How to get rid of Cannot await 'void' in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, c#-6.0

Below is how my sample application looks like to explore `async/await` & `TPL`

```
class Program
{
    static async void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Order for breakfast");
        Breakfast obj = new Breakfast();
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => obj.MakeTea());
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => obj.ToastBread());
        Task t3 = Task.Run(() => obj.BoilEgg());
        Console.WriteLine("Breakfast ready");
        var res = await Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3); // LOE - throwing error
    }
}

class Breakfast
{
    //making a tea
    public string MakeTea()
    {
        return "tea";

    }

    //toasting bread
    public string ToastBread()
    {
        return "bread";
    }

    //boil eggs
    public string BoilEgg()
    {
        return "egg";
    }
}
```

at #LOE compiler is throwing build error as

> cannot await void

my query here is

1. I don't have methods as void still why it is throwing such error?
2. Why can't void be await?

How to get rid of this ?
Thanks!

Comment: Change the return type of the Main method from `static async void Main(string[] args)` to `static async` **Task** `Main(string[] args)`.

Comment: @Dennis1679, just checked still the same error

Comment: It's Task.WhenAll that you can await

Comment: @Dennis1679 that is completely wrong. I only mention it to prevent OP from getting misinformation. You can only await a Task or something that implements the awaitable pattern. Void returns nothing so there's nothing to await. You're describing a deadlock which is a different thing.

Comment: @Crowcoder You are completely right. I see now the error in what I wrote. I was mixing up two different things. Thank you for notifying me. To rectify my earlier comment: I meant to warn the OP about using async void as a return type and then calling async tasks from within it. Because in some situations, if your task inside the async void fails, there is no recovering from it. Your application is dead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should declare the three smaller tasks as `Task<string>` instead of `Task`, otherwise you won't get anything in `res`. Of course, that's not a problem if you don't need anything in `res`.

The more important issue here is that you should use [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `WaitAll`. The former returns a `Task` or `Task<T[]>` for you to await, whereas the latter just waits for the tasks to finish if they aren't already. Since you are `await`ing here, you should use `WhenAll`.

So your code should be:

```
Task<string> t1 = Task.Run(() => obj.MakeTea());
Task<string> t2 = Task.Run(() => obj.ToastBread());
Task<string> t3 = Task.Run(() => obj.BoilEgg());
Console.WriteLine("Breakfast ready");
var res = await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

// res will contain tea, bread and egg, in some order.
```

Comment: Yes. Correct Thanks! but wondering in what scenario I should use .WaitAll()

Comment: @Kgn-web When you want to wait for them synchronously. It's like calling [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8) on each of the tasks.

Comment: @Kgn-web If you can help it, never :)

Comment: @GabrielLuci, what do you mean?

Comment: @Kgn-web You should [avoid blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if at all possible - and it almost always is. Using `await Task.WhenAll` is always better than using `Task.WaitAll`.